# How do I resolve a relative path to an absolute path in C?

Tags: c, windows, filepath

I have a C console app where I need to output the absolute path to a file given a (possibly) relative path. What is the best way to do this in C in a Windows environment?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so what problems did you have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [_fullpath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/506720ff%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Works great! As in: fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", _fullpath(buffer, "./test.html", BUFSIZE));

Answer (score 4):

[GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should help you  on Windows.

> GetFullPathName merges the name of the current drive and directory
>   with a specified file name to determine the full path and file name of
>   a specified file.

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351479/getting-absolute-path-from-relative-in-vista-seems-to-fail-using-win32-shell-pat