# Return folder path of graphics in Qt projects

Tags: c++, qt

For designing a custom made pushButton I added a picture source (1):

```cpp
#include "mybutton.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QIcon>
#include <QPixmap>

MyButton::MyButton(QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent) {
  QPixmap pixmap("/home/myCode/MyButton/MyButton/graphics/myPicture.png"); //(1) picture source
  QIcon buttonIcon;
  buttonIcon.addPixmap(pixmap);
  this->setIcon(buttonIcon);
  this->setIconSize(pixmap.rect().size());


}
```

---

Of course, sometimes the local path to picture changes.
So instead I would like to tell Qt at compile time something like this: Path to file is workspacefolder/graphics/myPicture.png
Like in VS Code you can configure build tasks (tasks.json) for compiling with g++ and refer with variable ${workspaceFolder}.

---

I tried using functions of QDir-Class, but that one only return when debugging, not at compile time.

```cpp
qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
```

Is it possible to return the workspaceFolder with help of QDir-functions?

Comment: You probably need to pass that in from your QMake or CMake script.

Comment: Possible solution if you have c++20: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57284913/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57284913/487892)

Comment: In Qt you could also put this png file into a resource and use that in your code. [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mention adding resource file works fine.

1. Add new file: Qt->Qt Resource File (resource.qrc)
2. Project tree is added with "Resources"-folder
3. Open folder
4. Right-Click resource.qrc
5. Add Prefix /
6. Add image files to that prefix which are located in graphics folder
7. Right Click on object and copy path
8. Add copy as resource where you need it

---

In my above mentioned code result answer would look like this:

```cpp
QPixmap pixmap(":/graphics/myPicture.png");
```

---

Qt automatically adds resource file to .pro file
I guess thats the link to the compiler

```
RESOURCES += \
    resource.qrc
```

---

I already tested moving the project folder and renaming it. Image resources are working.

Answer (score 2):

Qt resource system is what you need, and then the images will be "rolled into" the executable file.